# Issues with Binance Package

Tags: enums, client, binance

Having some trouble importing the Binance package into python. Specifically, I can't run the following lines:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
```

When I install binance into my environment using [this link](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) [`pip install python-binance`], The code gets hung up on line one at `>> from binance.client import Client`. The import error I get is the following:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/name/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/name/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Admittedly I'm not an expert in managing envs so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: its probably a problem with M1 mac